# Does "etiology" refer to the the original source or can it refer to a middle cause?

Tags: meaning

This question was asked in my dental school class:

> What is the etiology of the diagnosis of the brain abscess? The original cause was an infected tooth which led to the proliferation of a certain bacteria which led to a brain abscess.

So how far back does the word *etiology* imply? Is the correct answer the infected tooth or the bacteria? Because bacteria was the direct cause of the brain abscess, but the infected tooth was the original cause of the bacteria's proliferation!

I believe the answer is the bacteria because that was the direct cause of the abscess but I would like the opinion of the literary wizards on this wonderful site.

Comment: Perhaps you need the definition from that dental school class.  Just because the word "etiology" can be used in different senses in English, does not mean it is used in those senses in dentistry.  Thus, in my opinion, "literary wizards" cannot answer your question.

Comment: As a question of English, my opinion is that any answer to  this question would be a matter of opinion. Whether, or not, caries or other dental pathology  led to the bacterial infection of the brain it was the bacteria that caused the infection. But the bacteria were introduced from the tooth. As a matter of English, there is no simple answer.

Comment: 'What is the etiology of the diagnosis ...' doesn't make sense to me. "Etiology of the diagnosis" only shows the Google hits generated here.

Comment: The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiology) article on etiology is helpful, I found, especially the explanation of scurvy's etiology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a literary wizard but i have experience in such and will offer my humble answer.

**etiology**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/etiology)

a. The study of **causes** or **origins**.
b. The branch of medicine that deals with the causes or origins of disease.

There can be more than one etiology in a chain that lead to the manifestation of disease.  The bacteria from the tooth may indeed be the etiology of the brain abscess. But there could have been a chain of etiologies that lead to same.  Trauma to tooth (10 years ago), leading to root canal (4 years ago), then abscess at tooth leading to an apical abscess (one year ago) and finally spread of infection to the brain.  In this case the academic discussion could say **trauma** was the proximate etiology

The infected tooth in your example could be the **proximate etiology** causing subsequent etiologies. The bacteria could be the **causative** agent. But clinically saying: **bacteria from the infected tooth** should suffice and earn you good marks.

Just saying

> I believe the answer is the bacteria because that was the direct cause
>   of the abscess

leaves open the possibility of the same bacteria from other sources.

Comment: Wow, this is a wonderful answer and very eye opening. I appreciate that you extended the source... really opened my eyes. 
Thank you